# Calculating the digits that occures the most in an array

Tags: python

The following code is supposed to find the most occurring digits in array and then return these digits in a list with ascending order:

For example [`1, 12, 23, 45, 21, 4]` should return `[1, 2]`.

```
def sol(a):
    z = ''.join([str(m) for m in a])

    di = {w:0 for w in range(10)}

    lst = []

    for i in ((z)):
        if di[int(i)] in di:
            di[int(i)] += 1
        else:
            di[int(i)] = 1

    maximum = max(di, key=di.get)

    print(di)

    for key, value in di.items():
        if value == di[maximum]:
            lst.append(key)

    return (lst)
```

It passes almost all test cases, but the remaining two are hidding (to prevent hard coding), any help what I should do to pass all the possible test cases?

Comment: Why is 3 one of the most occurring digits in your example? It occurs only once.

Comment: By mistake, the correct answer is [1,2], thanks.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Next time give us good formated code. Means correct indention and easier to read formating (see PEP8 for example). Use correct upper case letters (e.g. in the beginning of each sentence) on your text. You have to hellp us to help you.

Comment: Despite the quality of your code and question I don't see a problem. The result of your code is `[1, 2]` for me.

Comment: @buhtz what about the quality of the code?

Comment: First look into the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72514564/revisions) to see what I have modified on your code formating. Secondly ask the search engine of your trust and read about PEP8 to get an idea how to write code that is easy to read for other persons. And I still don't see the problem. Your own code produce the desired output `[1, 2]`. What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
   if di[int(i)] in di:
```

Should be:

```
   if int(i) in di:
```

Some comments:

- this check shouldn't be necessary, as you already added an entry in `di` for all ten digits.
- As the keys of your dictionary are consecutive integers starting at 0, you might as well use a list -- this will work faster.
- You could use more descriptive variable names. `z` is not telling much.

With a few other changes, that leads to this code:

```
def sol(lst):
    alldigits = ''.join(map(str, lst))
    counts = [0] * 10
    for digit in alldigits:
        counts[int(digit)] += 1
    maxcount = max(counts)
    return [digit for digit, count in enumerate(counts) if count == maxcount]
```

Comment: the only alternative that I suggest is on the 3rd line ```counts = [0] * 10``` 
replace it with ```counts = [0] * len(alldigits)```

With that you can get more solutions than a single one

Comment: @bilakos you seem to misunderstand the use of `counts`.

Comment: Don't know... I did took the time to analyze it and I understood the purpose of it as an array. The number ```10``` it has to do with the length of it. So I thought that it has to do also about the length of the variable ```algorithm```.

Don't know if it matters, but it works in both case scenarios.

Comment: @bilakos, you write *"The number 10 it has to do with the length of it."*: no it hasn't. *"it works in both case scenarios"*: no, it doesn't. Try to call your adapted version with `sol([9])`

Comment: You are right.
Can you tell me how did you came up with the number 10?

Comment: The number 10 is the base of the *decimal* numbering system. One digit in the decimal notation has a value between 0 and 9, and such a digit serves as an index here, so we need a list of size 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of the standard library.
I'll go through the steps in IPython, so you can see what happens.

First, convert the list of ints to a list of digits:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 12, 23, 45, 21, 4]
Out[1]: [1, 12, 23, 45, 21, 4]

In [2]: b = [str(j) for j in a]
Out[2]: ['1', '12', '23', '45', '21', '4']

In [3]: import itertools

In [4]: d = [int(c) for c in itertools.chain.from_iterable(b)]
Out[4]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

Then count the digits, get those that occur more than once and sort them:

```
In [5]: import collections

In [6]: e = collections.Counter(d)
Out[6]: Counter({1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1})

In [7]: sorted(value for value, occurrance in e.items() if occurrance >1)
Out[7]: [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I don't understand your question or you didn't post the correct examples, you say:

> [The code] is supposed to find the *most occurring digits* in array and then *return these digits in a list with ascending order*

I'm not sure this is what you're asking, but it does what you said in the statement above and it has the nice advantage of making your eyes bleed when you look at it.

```
import numpy as np

def count_digits(digits: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    np_arr = np.array([int(j) for x in digits for j in list(str(x))])
    val_counts = np.array(np.unique(np_arr, return_counts=True)).T
    return list(val_counts[val_counts[:, 1].argsort()].T[0])
```

Example:

```
count_digits([1, 12, 23, 45, 21, 4])
# [3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
```